# GHashTableIter set GtkSpinButton to it's Adjustable

Tags: c, gtk, hashtable

I need to alter components of my `GHashTable` - `SpinButtons` - to their `Adjustments`

I assumed this would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't. Gdb doesn't help much (`step` just steps over)

```
GHashTableIter adjusthashtable;
gpointer key, value;

g_hash_table_iter_init (&adjusthashtable, widgetbuffer);
while (g_hash_table_iter_next (&adjusthashtable, &key, &value)) 
{
    if(strcmp(G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(value),"GtkSpinButton") == 0){
        value = gtk_spin_button_get_adjustment(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-insert the new value into the hashtable with the old key. The only problem is that that might invalidate your iterator, so you might need to reinitialize it. You can also check if the widget is a spin button much more efficiently than you are doing now, so the inner loop would become:

```
if(GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON(value)) {
    g_hash_table_insert(widgetbuffer, key, gtk_spin_button_get_adjustment(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(value)));
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&adjusthashtable, widgetbuffer);
}
```

Comment: That `GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON()` thing is a godsend. But I know for sure that messing with the hash table will cause a problem because "Modifying the hash table after calling this function invalidates the returned iterator." and `g_hash_table_iter_init()` would start from the beginning again.

Comment: Yes, but there's no way to advance the iterator to a certain item, so you just have to start from the beginning each time. After you've changed one spin button to an adjustment, it won't trigger the `GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON` again the next time.

Comment: You should probably look into a different approach to what you're doing though.

Comment: I tried something else that isn't working either, I'll just mark this solved.